# Pod warning message during dependancies file installation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoapods

Can anyone help to resolve the pod installation warning.  When i install pod files using pod init command in terminal, I am getting below warning message:

App target overrides the `ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation    - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or    - Remove the build settings from the target.

What will be the solution to solve it?

FYI : Cocoapod version is 0.39.0 and Xcode version is 7.3.1.